# Unable to start python in windows

Tags: python, chocolatey

Earlier I had installed Python 3.5 using chocolatey but when I found that libraries that I need to make use only is allowed only for Python version 2 - I uninstalled Python 3.5 and then install Python 2.7.3 from Control Panel.

I ensured that I set the PATH variable correctly for Python -

```
PATH=....;C:\Python27
```

but still when I invoke python from prompt I get the below error :

```
C:\>python 
Cannot find file at '..\\lib\python3\tools\python.exe' 
(C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\python3\tools\python.exe). This usually 
indicates a missing or moved file.
```

How do I set the chocolatey package manager issue resolved?

Comment: take a look at your evironment variables

Comment: looks like `PYTHONHOME` remains set.

Comment: PYTHONHOME does not seems to be set - C:\>echo %PYTHONHOME% %PYTHONHOME%

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same issue after I had run `chocolatey uninstall python` and uninstalled in other python versions in control panel. I was able to resolve it by removing the python.exe and pythonw.exe from the chocolatey bin directory (C:\ProgramData\Chocolatey\bin).

```
del C:\ProgramData\Chocolatey\bin\pytho*.exe
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Check that environment variables listed [here](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#environment-variables) have correct values.

For example

```
C:\>set PYTHONHOME=C:\Python27
```

Comment: I tried that but it still gives the same issue - C:\>set PYTHONHOME=C:\Python27                                                                                                                                  C:\>python                                                                      Cannot find file at '..\\lib\python3\tools\python.exe' (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\python3\tools\python.exe). This usually indicates a missing or moved file.

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot find file at '..\lib\**python3**\tools\python.exe'

Did you ensure that you have installed your Python **2**.7.3 into this folder?

> ...\python**3**\ ...

May you just need to change that path to

> '..\lib\python**2**\tools\python.exe'

Comment: I had installed Python 3.5 via chocolatey  and 2.7 via MSI installation. I am not sure where chocolatey deployed earlier Python - so I need to uninstall & install Python via chocolatey always?

Comment: Then I would assume you have either set a a PATH variable to '..\\lib\python3\tools\python.exe' or you have a USER-variable with python='..\\lib\python3\tools\python.exe'

Comment: No the PATH and PYTHONHOME variables are configured correctly - I feel the issue is with chocolately - I am unsure how to fix this issue

Comment: If you want to start python from a windows command line with the `$ python` command, and your get the above error, your windows machine somewhere has a environment variable to that location: '..\lib\python3\tools'. You just need to find that entry. Tools like the rapid-environment-editor could help you to find deprecated environment variable entries (if exist).

Answer (score 0):

You must add python 2 to your path.
If you are sure you have done that, restart your computer to ensure it's using the correct path variables.

Comment: This answer doesn't help more kind of comment